# Stop navigation overlapping footer

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation list on the left hand side of my screen, however this list overlaps my footer. I want my footer to be placed centrally right at the bottom of the page, below this, the navigation.

here is my CSS for my navigation & footer:

```
#playerMenu{
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:245px;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width:240px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    background: #4b4d59;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #535561 0%, #1f1f23 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #535562 0%, #202023 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #535562 0%, #202023 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #535562 0%, #202023 100%);
}



#playerMenu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}

#playerMenu li a{
    transition: color .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: color .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: color .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: color .3s ease;
    border-bottom: : 1px solid #393942;
    border-top: 1px solid #393942;
}

#playerMenu a {
    display:block;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
} 




.footer {
    width: 680px;
    height: 20px;
    margin:auto;
}

.footerContent {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #535561 0%, #1f1f23 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #535562 0%, #202023 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #535562 0%, #202023 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #535562 0%, #202023 100%);   
}

.footer p {
    float:left; width:100%; text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your web site. Here's why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Hint: don't use absolute-positioning if you don't want overlap.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise, removed link. Thanks!

Comment: I thought it would be something to do with that, however when I try new positioning effects it isn't placed where I want it too, any more hints on what positioning to use?

Answer (score 0):

Place all your content in a container div and then place your footer in another div:

```
<body>
<containerdiv>
<!-- All content -->
</containerdiv>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: done this however it doesn't seem to be working, should I be removing / adding some extra positioning?